# Add-on to open several Twitter/Gmail/etc accounts in the same Firefox?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox, I often use several accounts of the same webapp in parallel.

For instance a Twitter account for each of my projects, and several Gmail accounts for various purposes I don't want to mix.

Right now I use different browsers, and setting up each browser to my tastes takes a considerable time. I also tried running Firefox from different UNIX user accounts, but that's quite a pain to run.

Is there an add-on (or browser, or anything) that would allow me to do all of this in the same Firefox window?

I am also open to switching to a different browser, as long as it is an open source browser.
If the solution is an add-on, I prefer the add-on to be open source and if not at least free.

Comment: For *Gmail* you can log into multiple accounts at once and switch at will - and use different accounts in different tabs. But that is a built in *Gmail* thing not due to the browser.

Comment: I think there will hardly be a browser to support your needs. The problem is that your authentication data is associated with a user session, which is created per client (per browser) on the serverside of the corresponding application (Twitter, Gmail, Facebook and etc.) Some applications like Gmail support multiple accounts per browser session, because of their specific implementation. The latter is not a standard and one should not expect other services (like Twitter) to support it. The closest thing I have used is multiple browsers - one per account, or browsers started by different users.

Comment: As for starting Firefox by different OS user, it might become a good and easy thing to do if you automate the tedious scripts. I'd create shell script file per user and use it as a launcher for the browser. So I'd have project1.sh to launch firefox for project1 user with its own set of tabs, project2 and etc. Combied with the pin-tabs capability of firefox, this would be a good way to solve your issues. So - try and go with scripts. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Instead of starting Firefox using multiple OS users, have you considered using it with [multiple profiles](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager)? Using the [ProfileSwitcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/profileswitcher/) addon (I've not yet tested this, or I'd made it an answer), this might even be a much easier approach.

Comment: [Multifox](http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/) (which is a [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/multifox/)) allows this **per window**, but its beta, [AllAccounts](https://github.com/hultmann/allaccounts), seems to allow this **per tab**.

Comment: @unor: Thanks to your tip, I have been using Multifox for a few days and it seems to be what I was looking for! Could you please post an answer? (or I can do it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Multifox**](http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/) is a [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/multifox/) that

> allows Firefox to connect to websites using different user names. Simultaneously!

Those identities are called *Identity Profiles*, which can be named (e.g., "Private", "Work", and "Sockpuppet"). Cookies are shared only within a given Identity Profile (so if you have several windows open with the same Identity Profile, then you have the same cookies on these tabs).

You can switch identities from the toolbar:

> [image: Multifox screenshot: toolbar menu for switching identities]

So this solution is similar to having different Firefox profiles (which also could be opened from within Firefox, e.g. with the [ProfileSwitcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/profileswitcher/) add-on). The primary difference is, of course, that with Multifox you are using the *same* Firefox, i.e., you have the same settings, the same add-ons, etc., while each profile would give you a *new* Firefox.

There is also a sibling project [**AllAccounts**](https://github.com/hultmann/allaccounts), but it less ready for public:

- [it's "for tests only, may break some sites"](https://getmultifox.com/allaccounts/)
- [haven't been updated in a while](https://github.com/hultmann/allaccounts)
- [it's most lively fork continue in a slightly different direction of password management](https://github.com/bwinton/allaccounts/network).

(You [should not](https://github.com/hultmann/multifox/issues/131#issuecomment-31104255) use both add-ons at the same time.)